# Значение xml тэга объектного типа с использованием XStream

Tags: java, xml, сериализация

Использую библиотеку XStream, появилась проблема, решение которой в документации не нашел.
Какой XML хочу получить на выходе:

```
<boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
```

Для этого создаю класс BoolProp:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XStreamAlias("boolProp")
public class BoolProp {
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String name;
}
```

Все корректно, остается только добавить значение:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XStreamAlias("boolProp")
public class BoolProp {
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

Вот тут все и ломается, вывод:

```
  <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">
    <value>false</value>
  </boolProp>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вместо отдельного тэга value сделать value для тэга boolProp.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: [Field as Text Value](https://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html)?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо огромное! Если оформите в виде ответа - смогу отметить как ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html) вам нужен аттрибут `XStreamConverter`

```
@XStreamAlias("message")
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"content"})
class RendezvousMessage {

    @XStreamAlias("type")
    private int messageType;

    private String content;
    
    @XStreamConverter(value=BooleanConverter.class, booleans={false}, strings={"yes", "no"})
    private boolean important;

    @XStreamConverter(SingleValueCalendarConverter.class)
    private Calendar created = new GregorianCalendar();

    public RendezvousMessage(int messageType, boolean important, String content) {
        this.messageType = messageType;
        this.important = important;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Результат

```
<message type="15" important="no" created="1154097812245">This is the message content.</message>
```